# How can I sprout turtles in a patch in a circle layout inside all the patches they sprout in?

Tags: netlogo

I need to sprout turtles in a circle layout inside patches. I have tried `layout-circle`, but it's not working:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = 105]
[
    if not any? turtles
    [
      sprout-turtles 5
      ask turtles-here
      [
        set shape "circle"
        set size 0.2
        set color white
        layout-circle puestos-de-pie 0.4 (not correct)
      ]    
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be anywhere inside a circle (of radius 0.2 for this example):

```
ask turtles [ forward random-float 0.2 ]
```

If you want them to form a circle:

```
ask turtles [ forward 0.2 ]
```

The trick here is that `sprout` creates them in the centre and with a random `heading`/ So moving them `forward`, they stay in a circle.

If you want them evenly spaced around the circle, you will need to give them appropriate headings. The easiest way to do this while you are creating them is to have a variable that increases by the correct amount. Here is a self contained example to show you what I mean.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  let now-heading 0
  let num-turtles 20
  create-turtles num-turtles
  [ set heading now-heading
    forward 2
    set now-heading now-heading + 360 / num-turtles
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thats the issue. They sprout with a random heading so if they `fd 0.2` they do not form a circle. I mean, if there were many turtles and they `fd 0.2` they should form a circle but as they are 5 they distribute unevenly. My native language is spanish, I hope I can make me understand

Comment: okay, i think I understand. They form a circle, but are not evenly spaced around that circle.